# Liquibase is unable to find changelog file for integration tests with versions 4.0 and higher

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, testcontainers, changelog

I have a Spring Boot test to check if the Gradle embedded Postgres database has been successfully created. I'm using [TestContainers with the JDBC URL](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/) and an init function for liquibase.

```
public class TestcontainersPgIT {

    public static final String EMBEDDED_JDBC_URL = "jdbc:tc:postgresql:12.5://localhost:5432/postgres?TC_INITFUNCTION=<package names>.db.LiquibaseRunner::runUpdate";

    @Test
    public void testEmbeddedPg() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(EMBEDDED_JDBC_URL);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select 1");
        assertTrue(rs.next());
        String result = rs.getString(1);
        assertEquals("1", result);
    }
```

What happens above is that the line `Connection conn =...` will end up calling my liquibase runner function below.

```
public final class LiquibaseRunner {

    private LiquibaseRunner() {
    }

    public static void runUpdate(Connection connection) throws LiquibaseException {
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));

        Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("src/test/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-test.xml", new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
        liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```

The line that creates the new liquibase instance and passes in a path ( `Liquibase liquibase = new...` ) to the changelog file is the source off these errors in any Liquibase version >= 4.0. It seems unable to find the changelog file inside my `tests/resources/db/changelog` directory.I know this directory is copied over into the JAR/Build when it is compiled so I know the files are there. The error it throws is shown below.

```
Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:82)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:15)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:377)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:230)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2369)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:217)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:203)
```

I've tried many different file paths to be passed in, including using `class path` and relative file paths and it's still unable to find the changelog file for integration tests.

Filepaths I've tried

1. `classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-test.xml`
2. `classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-test.xml`
3. Relative file paths

Answer (score 0):

You may just need this path `resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-test.xml` or this path: `../test/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-test.xml`.

Comment: I have tried both of these it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ClassLoaderResourceAccessor Instead of the FileSystemResourceAccessor:

```
ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor = new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor();
```

Then, just access your changelog relatively to your resource folder:

```
new Liquibase("db/changelog/db.changelog-test.xml")
```